# ¿Cómo contar registros en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito contar los registros de una columna estas relacionarlas con otra columna.

Estas son las dos columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es hacer una consulta que me salga la cantidad de 1 del `dni` 72489076 y de los demás `dni`,

```
cantidad | dni  
      50 | 72489076  
      50 | 78585585
```

De esa forma lo que hecho es:

```
SELECT flag_asis,dni FROM detalle_asistencia dt

where flag_asis='1'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo puedes solucionar usando:

- [**`COUNT()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html): método que sirve para contar la cantidad de ocurrencias
- [**`GROUP BY`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modificador que sirve para agrupar registros de un mismo valor

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(flag_asis) AS cantidad, dni
FROM detalle_asistencia
WHERE flag_asis='1'
GROUP BY dni
```

Comment: gracias amigo, como hari si necitaria filtrar solo que llegan a contar 50 le pongo  WHERE flag_asis='1' and COUNT(flag_asis)='50' GROUP BY dni o WHERE flag_asis='1' and cantidad='50'  GROUP BY dni pero no funciona me sale error

Comment: @ingswsm, esa es otra pregunta que tranquilamente puedes formular. A modo de pista te recomiendo que leas [`Group by handling`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Excelente respuesta Marcos Gallardo. @ingswsm si quieres limitar la cantidad de resultados en MySQL puedes usar [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) al final de la cláusula. Algo así como: `SELECT  ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 50`

Comment: Creo que se refería a contar un máximo de 50: _como haría si necesitara filtrar solo que llegue a contar 50_